# Computing probability of one random variable less than another -- how to approach?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I have 2 random variables X~U[-2,2], Y~U[0,1].  Lets define two new random variables $A=(X+Y)^2$, $B=X^2-Y^2$ .

What is the exact numerical value of the probability of $Pr(A<B)$?

My approach to solve this problem is to make a new random variable $Z=A-B$ and then to compute $F_Z(z)=Pr(Z<z)$ and finally solve for $F_z(0)=Pr(Z<0)=(A-B<0)$.

This is the only approach I can think of to solve this.  Does this seem like an efficient approach?

Comment: Hint: $(X+Y)^2 - (X^2 - Y^2) = X^2 + 2XY + Y^2 - X^2 + Y^2 = 2(XY + 2Y^2)$. This is negative exactly when $X+Y$ is negative (because $2Y$ is nonnegative). Now you can just draw a picture of the rectangle $[-2, 2] \times [0, 1]$ and shade in various parts of it.

Comment: Thanks. I actually factored it to be P(X+Y<0), graphed, and then shaded in the region of the left of the line which intersects the pdfs of X and Y.  The pdf have am amplitude of 4.  Integrating to the left of P(X+Y<0) you get (1+1/2)/4 = 3/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. We have $$\Pr(Z<0){=\Pr(A<B)\\=\Pr(2XY+Y^2<-Y^2)\\=\Pr(X<-Y)\\={3\over 8}}$$

Comment: I just computed this on my own and got 3/8.  Thanks!